# overlap versus overlapping as nouns

Tags: difference, nouns

It seems that both overlap and overlapping can be used as nouns. What are their differences then? Can they be both used as countable nouns with the same meaning? Thanks!

Comment: Use *overlap* when you are talking about the resultant condition, use *overlapping* when you are talking about the action.

Answer (score 1):

True, *overlap* and *overlapping* both can be used as nouns. The difference is clear...

> [overlap (n):](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/OVERLAP)  flap that lies over another part AS IN *The overlap of the shingles should be at least ten inches.* 
>   [overlapping (n)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=overlapping): covering with a design in which one element covers a part of another AS IN *Do the job carefully. The overlapping should be perfect or else it won't look symmetrical.*

Please note that *overlapping* as a noun is [very rare.](http://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/overlapping.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Well

Overlap - noun
Overlapping - Adjective, used as a noun very rarely (hey there is an exception to everything)

That is the difference between Overlap and Overlapping.

I think by now you know what overlap and overlapping mean so I am not gonna discuss about their respective meanings.

Overlap can be used as both a countable noun and an uncountable noun. I found the following examples "[Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/overlap_2)" and I think they are very simple but good examples, as follows

Overlap:

Uncountable: There is (a) considerable overlap between the two subjects.
Countable : an overlap of 5 cm on each roof tile

Well overlap can be used as a countable noun. In the case of overlapping, its usage as a noun is very rare, that being the case, using it as a countable noun, well I am not very sure if it is possible, but I will go ahead and say no.